# How do I group by and order by count in Rails through a join table?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

How do I translate this SQL into Rails?

```
select tags.tag, count(*) c 
  from taggings, tags 
  where taggings.post_id = 1 and taggings.tag_id = tags.id 
  group by tag 
  order by c desc;
```

I tried to use

> Post.first.tags.select(:tag, "count(*) as count").group(:tag).order(count: :desc)

but it gave an error

> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

#### Models

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tags, :through => :taggings


class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Posts.first.tags.select("tags.tag, count(1) as tag_count").group('tags.tag').order('tag_count desc')
```

Comment: Wow that worked. I guess you have to have an intimate knowledge of how Rails constructs the SQL. I thought you could use `:tag` values, but  I guess sometimes you need raw SQL fragments.